# What is the theological position of Arya Samaj?

Tags: vedanta, advaita, vishishtadvaita, dvaita

I would like to know how Arya Samaj perceives God(Brahman).Do they consider themselves Advatins or Dvatins (Or even Vedantists for that matter)?

Comment: They view it as impersonal to be united with as the rays of the sun are people and god is the sun.

Comment: @Wikash_ so they are Advatins...

Comment: @Ikshvaku really? I agree with you except with the only rig veda part..they promote all 4 vedas as far as i know.

Comment: I updated answer

Answer (score 1):

> What is the theological position of Arya Samaj?

**[Arya Samaj](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arya_Samaj#Foundation) is a modern, Hindu reformist movement that was heavily influenced by Western beliefs. It was founded when India was under the iron fist of British rule, and its founder, [Dayananda Saraswati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dayananda_Saraswati), was a British-educated Indian nationalist and social reformer.**

From Wikipedia:

> Arya Samaj is a monotheistic Indian Hindu reform movement that promotes values and practices based on the belief in the infallible authority of the Vedas. The samaj was founded by the sannyasi (ascetic) Dayanand Saraswati on 10 April 1875.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arya_Samaj#Foundation) Members of the Arya Samaj believe in one God and reject the worship of idols.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dayananda_Saraswati)

Its beliefs are:

- Belief that moksha is not eternal
- Rejection of idol worship
- Rejection of animal sacrifice
- Rejection of many rituals such as shraddha
- Rejection of the supernatural and "superstitions"
- Belief in only one God
- Emphasis on Agnihotra and Gayatri mantra
- Rejection of the Upanishads as part of the Vedas
- Rejection of the Puranas
- Belief that the Vedic Samhitas are revealed, whereas the Upanishads are authored
- Interpreting the Vedas in an allegorical, metaphorical, or speculative way
- Rejection of the caste system and belief in caste and gender equality and equal rights (feminism)
- Anti-Brahminism

From [britannica.com](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Arya-Samaj):

> The Arya Samaj opposes worship of murtis (images), animal sacrifice, shraddha (rituals on behalf of ancestors), basing caste upon birth rather than upon merit, untouchability, child marriage, pilgrimages, priestly craft, and temple offerings.

As you can see, this movement was heavily influenced by Western beliefs.

The Arya Samaj is also fulfilling many of the prophecies of Kali yuga:

> It has worked to further intercaste marriage

This sect is rejected as heretical by the Orthodox followers of Hinduism such as the followers of the Ramanujacharya, Madhvacharya, and Shankaracharya sampradayas.

> Do they consider themselves Advatins or Dvatins (Or even Vedantists for that matter)?

They believe in a philosophy that is similar to Dvaita Vedanta (Dualism of Jiva and Paramatma). They are not Advaitins.

Comment: Can you cite some sources? AFAIK they equally criticize both Advatins and Dvatins.